# Error in the Three.js animation loop time

Tags: three.js, gltf

I’m studying three.js and making some experiments. I created a div and inserted the canvas inside this div to show a 3D model just in one part of my html/css website. After loading this model, I started to search how to initiate the gltf animation.

```
//Model
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer()

// Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    '/Windy/scene.gltf',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {
    const model = gltf.scene
    scene.add(model);

    const animationClip = gltf.animations[0];
    console.log(animationClip)

    const action = mixer.clipAction(animationClip, model);
    action.play();
    },
);

const clock = new THREE.Clock();

const animation = () => {
  controls.update()
  mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
};

animation();
```

I don’t know why, but when I start the animation everything looks duplicating and a lot fast. I think that I’m making mistakes on the clock usage, but I don’t get how to solve this. Can anyone help, please?

This is the original animation:
[A Windy Day - Download Free 3D model by Loïc Norgeot (@norgeotloic) [fb78f4c] (sketchfab.com)](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/a-windy-day-fb78f4cc938144e6902dd5cff354d525)

I made a OBS video from my animation: [Take a look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tLdk3SmfiJTCKHRd_cvLuBojUVQx6c1T/view?usp=drive_link)

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I've downloaded the asset from sketchfab as glb and it seems this is not an animation related issue. The entire asset looks strange and not comparable to the original asset at sketchfab. I could imagine that the glTF exporter at sketchfab does not properly process the file. Other (non-three.js) glTF viewers like https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ also produce a wrong result.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's a mistake in the way you're updating the animation and the clock. The clock's getDelta() function returns the time elapsed since the last frame update. However, in your current setup, you're creating a new clock for every animation frame, which can lead to erratic animation behavior.

```
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer();

loader.load(
    '/Windy/scene.gltf',

    function (gltf) {
        const model = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(model);

        const animationClip = gltf.animations[0];
        console.log(animationClip);

        const action = mixer.clipAction(animationClip, model);
        action.play();
    }
);

const animation = () => {
    controls.update();

    // Update the clock only once per frame
    const delta = clock.getDelta();
    mixer.update(delta);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
};

animation();
```

By creating the clock outside the animation loop and updating it once per frame, you should see more consistent and smooth animations without the duplication and excessive speed.